# Tag Badge Hover Font

Tags: bug, design

Has anyone noticed the font of the details in the tag badges when hovered?

[image]

Here's the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40012068/how-can-i-call-the-controls-of-a-form-from-another-form-in-winforms).

I viewed it using `Google Chrome Version 53.0.2785.143 m`

It's kinda different based on the font family that the site uses.

Seems kinda off for me or is it really like this way?

Comment: Post the link to that page please?

Comment: It seems off to me too.

Comment: Oops. Sorry but what does OC mean here?

Comment: Sorry, I deleted the comment. OCD is a disorder (dunno if I really have one) in which you became compulsive and obsessive for some things. For example, I saw something's off in the design of this one, I can't help but to think of it every time that puts me to unease. It will bother me unless I do something about it. Well, that's OCD in my definition.

Comment: Join the club. I have that too, the reason why I asked you for question link :D

Comment: Where do I sign? :)

Comment: [Cross-site duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285049/260312).

Comment: That background color is also quite abrupt when you accidentally hover over the tag, considering its brightness and contrast with the other colors.

Comment: a bigger bug to me is that the tooltip renders **on** the tag, and since it doesn't have `user-select: none` nor is it a child of the tag's element, it keeps going in and out when the cursor is on it... https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmF52.gif (FF50 and chrome 54 on osX10.9 non retina)

Comment: @Kaiido Post a Meta question about it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The JS is appending the HTML of the message between `</body>` and `</html>`, causing it to lose part of the styling.

[image: screenshot of HTML]