# Mouse hover on dupe hammer causes repeated open and close of popup

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, design, dupehammer

If a gold badge user closes a question as duplicate using their hammer after others have already voted to close it as a duplicate the banner moves slightly over the badge. If the mouse is then in the top right corner of the badge it will open the popup banner and then as the mouse goes onto the banner close it resulting in it opening and closing lots of times:

[image: Open and close issue]

Please avoid any meta affect on the question but you should be able to reproduce it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40932634/console-read-failure-in-c-sharp).

Comment: To reproduce this you might need to make your browser window smaller. (I had to)

Comment: [Cross site duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287473/295232).

Comment: That's the hidden "Disco" feature.

Comment: @Stijn Us with tiny monitors do not need to do that!

Comment: But you with tiny monitors need a little disco in your life.

Comment: [Disco's Dead](https://youtu.be/CqSzAwFr7cY)

Comment: I bet it has something to do with focus and not inheriting focus.

Comment: Also, what's with the font inside? Doesn't seem to match the rest of the site. There must already be a question about that...

Comment: @Henders [MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336201/tag-badge-hover-font) and [MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285049/missing-font-on-some-error-and-dupehammer-info-popups)

Comment: Looks like the position calculation for that element is done using the height of that element with a single line (shows the element nicely just on top of the badge element) instead of using the real height.

Comment: I came here for close/reopen disco.

Comment: Here's what happens in my company: Status: resolved, won't fix. Reason: there's an easy workaround available (just move the mouse somewhere else). And: BTW, why do you test this, it's not your task.